# RabbitMQ - Does one consumer block the other consumers of the same queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm in a phase of learning RabbitMQ/AMQP from the RabbitMQ documentation. Something that is not clear to me that I wanted to ask those who have hands-on experience.
I want to have multiple consumers listening to the same queue in order to balance the work load. What I need is pretty much close to the ["Work Queues" example in the RabbitMQ tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html).
I want the consumer to acknowledge message explicitly after it finishes handling it to preserve the message and delegate it to another consumer in case of crash. Handling a message may take a while.
My question is whether AMQP postpones next message processing until the previous message is ack'ed? If so how do I achieve load balancing between multiple workers and guarantee no messages get lost?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, the other consumers don't get blocked. Other messages will get delivered even if they have unacknowledged but delivered predecessors. If a channel closes while holding unacknowledged messages, those messages get returned to the queue.

See [RabbitMQ Broker Semantics](http://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html)

> Messages can be returned to the queue using AMQP methods that feature a requeue parameter (basic.recover, basic.reject and basic.nack), or due to a channel closing while holding unacknowledged messages.

---

EDIT In response to your comment:

Time to dive a little deeper into the [AMQP specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf) then perhaps:

> **3.1.4 Message Queues**
>
> A message queue is a named FIFO buffer that holds message on behalf of a set of consumer applications.
>   Applications can freely create, share, use, and destroy message queues, within the limits of their authority.
>   Note that in the presence of multiple readers from a queue, or client transactions, or use of priority fields,
>   or use of message selectors, or implementation-specific delivery optimisations the queue MAY NOT
>   exhibit true FIFO characteristics. The only way to guarantee FIFO is to have just one consumer connected
>   to a queue. The queue may be described as “weak-FIFO” in these cases. [...]
>
> **3.1.8 Acknowledgements**
>
> An acknowledgement is a formal signal from the client application to a message queue that it has
>   successfully processed a message.[...]

So acknowledgement confirms processing, not receipt. The broker will hold on to the message until it's gotten acknowleged, so that it can redeliver them. But it is free to deliver more messages to consumers even if the prededing messages have not yet been acknowledged. The consumers will not be blocked.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I couldn't find the answer to the first part ("No, the other consumers don't get blocked.") anywhere in the docs. It is exactly the behavior I'm looking for. On the other hand it breaks the queue semantics, doesn't it? The messages may be processed out of order.

Comment: Edited the answer. Yes, the messages may be processed by the consumers out of order.

Comment: Thanks for adding the clarification about FIFO. Thorough and clear answer.

Comment: @flup If an unacknowledged message gets nack or reject, where does it go? At the top or bottom of the queue ?

Comment: @guiomie That is implementation-specific. [the docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) say: [...] Any of these scenarios caused messages to be requeued at the back of the queue for RabbitMQ releases earlier than 2.7.0. From RabbitMQ release 2.7.0, messages are always held in the queue in publication order, even in the presence of requeueing or channel closure.

Comment: Are you aware if theres a way to apply pre-2.7.0 behavior to a post 2.7.0 rabbitmq ?

Comment: If there is exactly one consumer and only message gets delivered to consumer at a time, why there remains more than one message unacknowledged ?