# RabbitMQ - Non Blocking Consumer with Manual Acknowledgement

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm just starting to learn RabbitMQ so forgive me if my question is very basic.

My problem is actually the same with the one posted here:
[RabbitMQ - Does one consumer block the other consumers of the same queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841843/rabbitmq-does-one-consumer-block-the-other-consumers-of-the-same-queue)

However, upon investigation, i found out that manual acknowledgement prevents other consumers from getting a message from the queue - blocking state. I would like to know how can I prevent it. Below is my code snippet.

...

```
var message = receiver.ReadMessage();
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", message);

// simulate processing
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);

receiver.Acknowledge();

public string ReadMessage()
{

   bool autoAck = false;
   Consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(Model);
   Model.BasicConsume(QueueName, autoAck, Consumer);
   _ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)Consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
   return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_ea.Body);
}

public void Acknowledge()
{

   Model.BasicAck(_ea.DeliveryTag, false);
}
```

Comment: Publish messages to an exchange, not directly a queue and then use one queue per consumer could solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I modify how I get messages from the queue and it seems blocking issue was fixed. Below is my code.

```
    public string ReadOneAtTime()
    {
        Consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(Model);
        var result = Model.BasicGet(QueueName, false);
        if (result == null) return null;
        DeliveryTag = result.DeliveryTag;
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Body);
    }

    public void Reject()
    {
        Model.BasicReject(DeliveryTag, true);
    }

    public void Acknowledge()
    {
        Model.BasicAck(DeliveryTag, false);
    }
```

Going back to my original question, I added the QOS and noticed that other consumers can now get messages. However some are left unacknowledged and my program seems to hangup. Code changes are below:

```
    public string ReadMessage()
    {
        Model.BasicQos(0, 1, false); // control prefetch
        bool autoAck = false;
        Consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(Model);
        Model.BasicConsume(QueueName, autoAck, Consumer);

        _ea = Consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_ea.Body);
    }

    public void AckConsume()
    {
        Model.BasicAck(_ea.DeliveryTag, false);
    }

    In Program.cs
    private static void Consume(Receiver receiver)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var message = receiver.ReadMessage();
            if (message == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO message received.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", message);
                receiver.AckConsume();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total message received {0}", counter);
    }
```

I appreciate any comments and suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the rabbit provides infrastructure where one consumer can't lock/block other message consumer working with the same queue.
The behavior you faced with can be a result of couple of following issues:

1. The fact that you are not using auto ack mode on the channel leads you to situation where one consumer took the message and still didn't send approval (basic ack), meaning that the computation is still in progress and there is a chance that the consumer will fail to process this message and it should be kept in rabbit queue to prevent message loss (the total amount of messages will not change in management consule). During this period (from getting message to client code and till sending explicit acknowledge) the message is marked as being used by specific client and is not available to other consumers. However this doesn't prevent other consumers from taking other messages from the queue, if there are more mossages to take.

   IMPORTANT: to prevent message loss with manual acknowledge make sure
   to close the channel or sending nack in case of processing fault, to
   prevent situation where your application took the message from queue,
   failed to process it, removed from queue, and lost the message.
2. Another reason why other consumers can't work with the same queue is QOS - parameter of the channel where you declare how many messages should be pushed to client cache to improve dequeue operation latency (working with local cache). Your code example lackst  this part of code, so I am just guessing. In case like this the QOS can be so big that there are all messages on server marked as belonging to one client and no other client can take any of those, exactly like with manual ack I've already described.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believed since i did not call QOS and there were few messages in the queue, the broker sends only to one consumer. Thanks for pointing me that. However, as I added the QOS, i noticed that out of the 10 messages I sent and running a single consumer, only half are acknowledge. Messages 1, 3, 5,7, 9 are only acknowledge. Any idea on this?

Comment: Pay attention to your basic reject - you have multiple true, may be this is what leads to the following situation?

Comment: I modify and removed the Reject code but still did not work properly. I saw some codes that iterates the return values of BasicConsume. For now, I'll stick with the BasicGet.